# Check if an item matches a regex string

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm using this script:

```
import re

message = 'oh, hey there'
matches = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello']

def process(message):
    for item in matches:
        search = re.match(item, message)

    if search == None:
        return False
    return True

print process(message)
```

Basically, my aim is to check if any part of the `message` is inside any of the items in `matches`, however using this script, it always returns `False` (no match).

Could someone point out if I am doing something wrong in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) rather than [`match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match). As an optimization, [`match` only starts looking at the beginning of the string, rather than anywhere in it](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Additionally, you're only looking at the result of the last match attempt. You should check inside of the loop and return early if any match:

```
for item in matches:
    if re.search(item, message):
        return True
return False
```

Note that if you only care about substrings and don't need to match on regular expressions, just use [the `in` operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

```
for item in matches:
    if item in message:
        return True
return False
```

Comment: Well, changed it to `.search`, but the problem still persists.

Comment: @Markum: There was an additional problem. I have updated my answer to include it.

Answer (score 2):

As icktoofay's answer indicates, you should be using `re.search()` instead of `re.match()` if you want to search anywhere in the string, however for something this simple you could use a normal substring test:

```
message = 'oh, hey there'
matches = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello']

def process(message):
    return any(item in message for item in matches)

print process(message)
```